# How to limit a users uploaded image size using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering how would you limit an uploaded image size to 5mb using PHP & MySQL.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [`upload_max_filesize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) ini directive.

Answer (score 2):

depends on the method of upload really. For example within a standard HTML form you could add something like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="50000" />
```

There are also options from within PHP itself that can usually be controlled through .htaccess files, like this:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 5M
php_value post_max_size 5M
```

or through [ini_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) - all depends on your setup really.

Comment: this could be bypassed using a remote form on a different site.

Comment: Couldn't a user with firebug or something just change the "value" attribute on your hidden field and submit with whatever limit they wanted?

Comment: yep, there are always security considerations with HTML such as this. All depends on context though really.

Comment: Just to clarify, the HTML option is inherently an insecure solution, but under certain circumstances it can still be suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Use `if ($_FILE['yourfile']['size'] > (1024 * 5))` or restrict php using `ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '5MB');`

Comment: Can you use ini_set for upload_max_filesize?  I thought that the file had already been "passed" by the time the PHP code runs?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways.  The quickest, but least effective is to set the [MAX_FILE_SIZE](http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlupload.php) size in the HTML form.

The most effective is to change the PHP ini.  You need to set the following variables:

- [upload_max_filesize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize)
- [post_max_size](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) for all the details, but it will depend on the MAX_FILE_SIZE for the form, the upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in php.ini.  Some other parameters may come into play as well (e.g. max_input_time or memory_limit if the max file size is large enough).